# LR: VUgen web_set_timeout function unrealistic?

Tags: httpwebrequest, webtest, load-testing, loadrunner

I understand that VUGen's `web_set_timeout` function allows me to set a timeout value higher than the usual value (which seems to be 120 seconds).

What I do *not* understand: Doesn't this imply that all users would have to set their browser http POST timeout config value to a new, higher value? Don't I then test with a (simulated/virtual) user configuration that no real-world user would/could use?

Wouldn't I also require all proxies between the user and the webserver to be configured with an at-least-as-high timeout value to use a custom timeout value in the browser? Otherwise my user's transactions will fail while my load test would pass?

Context: Load test of an browser- (Ajax) based frontend with VUGen 9.51. Browser times out on web server request with `Error -27728 Step download timeout (120 seconds) has expired when downloading non-resource(s)`, and I hesitate using the web_set_timeout fore obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each browser has a different time-out value defined. This value can also be changed rather easily by users.

Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050 for info on IE timeouts.

In short it says:

```
Internet Explorer imposes a time-out limit for the server to return data. 
By default, the time-out limit is as follows:

Internet Explorer 4.0 and Internet Explorer 4.01    5 minutes
Internet Explorer 5.x and Internet Explorer 6.x    60 minutes
Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8        60 minutes

Internet Explorer does not wait endlessly for the server to come
back with data when the server has a problem.
```

Also many services that are used today are machine-to-machine services (othen SOAP requests
 are used for this) and they may have time-outs that are interface specific.

The place in VuGen where this is set from the UI is from the "*Run-Time Settings | Preferences | Options*" - in this list there are the following timeouts that can be set:

```
HTTP-Request connect timeout     default 120 seconds
HTTP-Request response timeout    default 120 seconds
```

In practice however, if a normal web-ui takes more than 5-10 seconds to respond to user clicks then the service will be considered slow by the users.

*The exception here is SAP EP where 30+ minutes of waiting for simple thins is OK ... :)*

Comment: Thanks for especially the link, but let me ask if that indirectly means the "[..] my user's transactions will fail while my load test would pass?" statement is true when I use larger http request timeouts in VUGen while my user's browsers don't?

Comment: If you know the limit of the transaction, then of course the timeout should be set to the known limit if you wish to fail it in the test. On the other hand I often encounter a situation where customers say they want to know how long it takes, so we set this value much higher than the accepted limit

Comment: Answer did not answer my question 1:1, but acknowledged my estimates and pointed me to the right direction. Thanks.